Is it possible to forward ports between two servers using socat and socks5 proxy?
We have server1 and server2

on server2 a socks5 proxy server is installed and listens on TCP port
1080

on server2 an openvpn server is installed that listens on TCP port
1194

server1 is connected to socks5 proxy (at server2) and listens on local port 1070.


Is it possible to do this using socat?:
We want to forward any packet sent to server1 port 9090 to server2 port 1194 using the socks5 tunnel. meaning if we change our openvpn configuration file and replace server2 IP with server1 IP and port 1194 with 9090. the connection is forwarded.
If the proxy type in server2 is HTTP when this answer by chatgpt works fine (we need to run apt install corkscrew first):
just run this in server1:
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9090,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:'corkscrew 127.0.0.1 1070

But what is the answer for socks5 proxy?

Socat 1.8.0.0 has an experimental socks5 client. Thus, the following command might do what you want:

socat --experimental TCP4-LISTEN:9090,reuseaddr,fork SOCKS5-CONNECT:127.0.0.1:1070:server2:1194

You might need to replace server2 with the appropriate IP address or even 127.0.0.1

Replacing server2 with the server2 IP address worked. socat 1.8.0.0 needs to be installed manually, the apt version is older.

If I understand you correctly, you just want to forward server1:9090 to server1:1070 - this should do what you want:
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9090,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:server2:1070

So, server1 listen address is 127.0.0.1 not 10.10.10.10

That server1, is it just a TCP forwarder to the socks5 proxy?
